# Permanently delete git repository with all its content without project id

Tags: git, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-repos

Is there any way to permanently delete a git repository without the need of the project.

I already have deleted the projects and they are not in the database any more.
however the git repositories stil are. how can these be deleted

Especially the tbl_content where all the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean-up job that can remove the rest of the content.

```
EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent 1
# You may have to run the following command multiple times, the last
# parameter is the batch size, if there are more items to prune than the 
# passed in number, you will have to run it multiple times
EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 100000
```

https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-clean-up-your-project-collection/

Comment: The link describes a api call to remove the repo from the recycle bin, Before running the stored procedures. The recycle bin cannot be emptyd because if don't have the projects any more. I tried running the stored procedures but notthing happens.

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me and would probably require a support call to fix.